# Salesforce add Activity History element to Lead (api) .net

Tags: .net, salesforce

My goal is to find Lead by id, and add to this lead Activity History (SendedEmail type)

I have list with lead id's and html body(email) i need to add this emails to Activity History of lead ,as it was sent from saleforce.

How can i build Activity History (SendedEmail type) element , and add it to my lead

```
//This what i am tried

SF.QueryResult _ExistingLead = m_SalesForceReference.query("Select  Lead_ID__c FROM Lead where Email='xxx.xx@com'");

 if (_ExistingLead.records.Count() != 0)
          {
//going throw all my leads
              foreach (SF.Lead item in _ExistingLead.records)
              {

  SF.ActivityHistory Activitymail = new SF.ActivityHistory();
  Activitymail.Id = item.Lead_ID__c;//here i added lead id to my ActivityHistory 
  Activitymail.Mobile__c = "123456";
  SF.SaveResult[] _SaveResults = m_SalesForceReference.create(new SF.sObject[] { Activitymail });
//not working
//No errors but i cant see it in the lead



                                }
                            }
```

What i am missing here?

How can i build Activity History (SendedEmail type) element , and add it to my lead?

Answer (score 0):

I count find how to add Activity History (is seems to be read only element)

But i font a way tyo do this by sending email from my lead and adding it to the Activity Historyy

Here  code

```
 SF.Lead MyLead = (SF.Lead)_ExistingLead.records[0];
 string OwnerId = MyLead.OwnerId;
 string Contact_ID__c = MyLead.Lead_ID__c;
 SF.SingleEmailMessage mail = new SF.SingleEmailMessage();
 String[] toAddresses = new String[] { "vovaLead@dd.com" };
 mail.toAddresses = (toAddresses);
 mail.bccSender = (true);
 String[] bccAddresses = new String[] { "vovaLeadBcc@dd2.com" };
 mail.bccAddresses = (bccAddresses);
 mail.targetObjectId = (Contact_ID__c);
 mail.saveAsActivity = (true);//THIS WILL ADD THIS EMAIL TO ACTIVITY HISTORY
 mail.subject = ("some text");
 mail.plainTextBody ="some text";
 SF.SendEmailResult[] _SaveResults = m_SalesForce.sendEmail(new SF.Email[] { mail });
```

And IMPORTANT make sure :

> Navigate to Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability to update
>   the Access Level to All Email.